# jqGrid JSON notation on objects

Tags: json, jqgrid, notation

there!
I´ve one column in my jqGrid that is empty.
But i checked the object on chrome console and thats fine.

**colModel definition**

```js
colModel:[
    {name:'id',index:'id', width:55,editable:false,editoptions:{readonly:true,size:10},hidden:true},
    {name:'firstName',index:'firstName', width:100,searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'cn']}},
    {name:'lastName',index:'lastName', width:100,editable:true, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{size:10}},
    {name:'books[0].nome',index:'books[0].nome', width:100,editable:true, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{size:10}},
    {"formatter":"myfunction", formatoptions:{baseLinkUrl:'/demo/{firstName}|view-icon'}}
]
```

**JSON response**

```json
{
    "total": "10",
    "page": "1",
    "records": "3",
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "firstName": "John",
            "lastName": "Smith",
            "books": [{"nome": "HeadFirst"}]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "firstName": "Jane",
            "lastName": "Adams",
            "books": [{"nome": "DalaiLama"}]
        },
        {
            "id": 35,
            "firstName": "Jeff",
            "lastName": "Mayer",
            "books": [{"nome": "Bobymarley"}]
        }
    ]
}
```

**chrome console inspect object**

```
rowdata.books[0].nome
"HeadFirst"
```

Any one know where theres are possibles trick?

Tks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use as the value of `name` property of `colModel` only the names which can be used as property name in JavaScript and as CSS id names. So the usage of `name:'books[0].nome'` is not good idea.

To solve your problem you can use `jsonmap`. For example you can use dotted name conversion:

```
{name: 'nome', jsonmap: 'books.0.nome', ...
```

In more complex cases you can use functions as the value of `jsonmap`. For example

```
{name: 'nome', jsonmap: function (item) {
        return item.books[0].nome;
    }, ...
```

You can find some more code examples about the usage of `jsonmap` in other old answers: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2706620/315935), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4641118/315935), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6904980/315935), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8150904/315935), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9867370/315935).

Answer (score 0):

`name` is intended to be a unique name for the row, not a reference to a JSON object. From the [jqGrid colModel options documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acolmodel_options):

> Set the unique name in the grid for the column. This property is required. As well as other words used as property/event names, the reserved words (which cannot be used for names) include subgrid, cb and rn.

You can also observe how `.name` is used within [grid.base.js](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.base.js) - for example:

```
var nm = {},
...
nm = $t.p.colModel[i].name;
...
res[nm] = $.unformat.call($t,this,{rowId:ind.id, colModel:$t.p.colModel[i]},i);
```

---

Anyway, to get back to your question I think you will have better luck by passing down the book name directly - as strings and not objects - and referencing it by name as something like `bookName`.