# Filtering in jqgrid with remote data and formatting

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a requirement to filter data locally in jqgrid without using the in-built UI. I followed the answer given by Oleg in the post [jqGrid Filtering Records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749723/jqgrid-filtering-records) . It worked like a charm with some changes for my setup. However, I cannot seem to get it working for a field where the records are formatted. The jqgrid data is remote.

Posting the code sample from [jqGrid Filtering Records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749723/jqgrid-filtering-records) as that is pretty much what I have:

```
$("#search").click(function() {
var searchFiler = $("#filter").val(), grid = $("#list"), f;

if (searchFiler.length === 0) {
    grid[0].p.search = false;
    $.extend(grid[0].p.postData,{filters:""});
}
f = {groupOp:"OR",rules:[]};
f.rules.push({field:"name",op:"cn",data:searchFiler});
f.rules.push({field:"note",op:"cn",data:searchFiler});
grid[0].p.search = true;
$.extend(grid[0].p.postData,{filters:JSON.stringify(f)});
grid.trigger("reloadGrid",[{page:1,current:true}]);
});
```

In my case, the field 'name' is formatted in the jqgrid:

```
{name:"name", index:"name", width:250, align:'left',
  formatter: function(cellvalue, options, rowObject)
{
  return rowObject.Data[0]['userName'];
}
 },
 ...
 jsonReader : {
        repeatitems:false,
         root: 'rows',
         userdata: 'rows'
      },
loadonce: true,      
viewrecords: true,
autowidth: true,
multiselect: false,
height: 500,    
rowNum: 999,
subGrid: true,
```

We make the query to the backend once and store the data in 'rows' for display in subgrid.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

thanks,

Asha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that you need use custom formatter in the case. I suppose that you can use `jsonmap`. Probably `jsonmap: "Data.0.userName"` will do want you need. Alternatively you can use `jsonmap` as function (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10731526/315935) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:315935%20%2bjsonmap%20%2barray)).

In general you should always define [unformatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter#unformatting) together with [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter). It could be the reason of your current problem.

Comment: Thank you so much, Oleg. It worked like a charm. I guess I never needed a formatter here. The    jsonmap: "Data.0.userName" worked. Now I am not sure why I used the custom formatter in the first place, because I am just essentially mapping data here. You gave me a lot of options here, so next time I can make a better decision.

Comment: For the filtering is it possible to make it case insensitive. I tried adding 'var searchFiler = $("#filter").val().toLowerCase(), f', but that will miss cases where I have something like 'Asha' in the 'name' field.

Comment: Never mind, added ignoreCase: true to the jqgrid that you mentioned in [Case insensitive wildcard filter with filterToolbar](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/case-insensitive-wildcard-filter-with-filtertoolbar/) . That worked. Thanks again.

Comment: @Asha: You can just include `ignoreCase: true` jqGrid option.