# How to get the value of row field (nested object) using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I am using Jquery grid to populate my data.
In one of my grids, I am populating nested object using,

```
{
name : 'student.roll',
index : 'student.roll',
sortable: false,
width : 120
```

}

Now that, I need to parse the list of roll numbers for some manipulation.

```
var lista = jQuery("#student-grid").getDataIDs();
 for(i=0;i<lista.length;i++){
rowData=jQuery("#student-grid").getRowData(lista[i]);

 }
```

From this when i try to get rowData.student.roll, its trying to fetch an object called student but its a field name out there. How can I fetch the value of roll from jqgrid? Please help.

Comment: can you please put the HTML codes too . just to get you better...

Comment: @MayurGupta : Its just a div to which I bind my whole jqgrid as a table. Something like
<div id = container> 
<table id="student-grid"></table>
</div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rowData["student.roll"]` form. By the way I don't recommend you to use `name` property in `colModel` with special characters like `.`. You can use `jsonmap` or `xmlmap` mostly to read the data from the server which have having special characters in the name. For example `name: 'student_roll', jsonmap: 'student.roll'` will be better. In some more complex cases you can use `jsonmap` defined as functions (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10731526/315935) for more references to code examples).

Comment: Thanks! it worked perfectly :) i used rowData['student.roll']. But now I am changing my colModel..

Answer (score 1):

ok you can do it in this way...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".button").click(function (e) {

                var value= $(this).closest('tr').find("span[id*=student-grid]").text();

                alert(value);
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    </script>
```